# apache to nginx rewrite issues

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I'm trying to convert

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

in to a nginx rewrite.

I was trying something like

```
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location @extensionless-php {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

to begin with but this doesn't seem to work. The redirect seems to kind of happen but the php file gets downloaded instead of parsed.  Any help or recommendations will help, thanks!

Comment: I could help but please explain to me the logic of the first rewrite.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady The first is taking anything with *.php and making it into a directory call. So for instance domain.com/faq.php would then rewrite to domain.com/faq/

Comment: I just noticed you said the downloading part, this means your code works but there's a problem with the `location ~ \.php$`, check the php settings, could be a wrong sock file or you should to be using a port, please paste me the line that begins with `listen` inside `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady  It's listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock.   If I just go to the host.com/ it renders right.  It's just the redirect that doesn't render.  It's like it's not sending the file back threw the "location ~ \.php" block.

Comment: try adding the rule directly to the `try_files`, `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php`

Comment: Thanks @MohammadAbuShady,  That works great for "host.com/page" but how about "host.com/page/" with the leading slash.

Comment: try adding this in the server scope above the location `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady That works but it's backwards.   I want  /page to redirect to /page/.   Then /page/ be rendered by page.php.  

currently /page renders to page.php and /page/ redirects /page. 
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50647/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-ryan-knopp)